# How to fix Lighthouse "Links do not have a discernible name"

Tags: html, css, lighthouse

Lighthouse suggesting to [fix my a href text](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/2.2/link-name?application=lighthouse)

I have a html like that

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/@some-name-here" target="_blank" rel="noopener" class="social-icon twitter grayscale"></a>
```

What is really happens here is I just displaying the image inside a href by using css class:

```
.social-icon.twitter {
  background: url('../images/logo-twitter.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

I can't do `<a....>Twitter</a>` as in that case the displayed text will destroy the view.

I can't think of anything else like just putting a `span` with a text inside my `a` and make it hidden e.g `<a....><span class="hide">Twitter</span></a>` but wonder if there is any proper solution?

Any recommendations on that?

Answer (score 243):

For accessibility reasons (required for screen readers) links must contain a text or have description in `aria-label` attribute. In many use cases like yours you don't want to add any text in a link, but instead use as image or any graphic element wrapper.

Fix it by adding `aria-label="Twitter"` to your `a` element, like

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/@some-name-here" aria-label="Twitter" target="_blank" rel="noopener" class="social-icon twitter grayscale"></a>
```

Comment: Can we make it spaced? e.g. "Find us on twitter?

Comment: @Nofel, yes, of course. Define whatever value for `aria-label`.

Answer (score 19):

If want to implement this in react app then, We need to add **aria-label** property to `<a>` tag.

**Before:**

```
<a href={`https://${ this.props.info }`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
   <i className="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
   <i className={ `fa fa-${ this.props.icon } fa-stack-1x fa-inverse` }></i>
</a>
```

**After:**

```
<a href={`https://${ this.props.info }`} aria-label={`${ this.props.name }`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
   <i className="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
   <i className={ `fa fa-${ this.props.icon } fa-stack-1x fa-inverse` }></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

**For SlickNav**
The solution is quite simple. **Just add title to the element** of the Javascript file which has aria-haspopup="true" and tabindex="0" attribute. Add title like title="Anything" in above-mentioned line. It will solve the problem.
Working example is [Oceanspace](https://www.oceanspace.in)

For other similar issues you have to add title attribute to the respective anchor element

[image: Problem was here]